# Storing page settings in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm probably going to get knocked because this is more of an architecture question then a coding question and I haven't tried anything.  I'm trying to decide WHAT to try ...

I have a web page with a list of user data in an ng-repeat.  Also on the page is a radio group and a select input with filtering options for the data.  All of that works fine.

If the user clicks on a link that is in the repeated user data, they "drill down" to a details page (this is NOT a SPA).  What's the best way to set things up so that when they select "Back" to return to the listing page the values from the radio group and select are restored?  Query params? Local Data storage?  What's the best "Angular" approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Angular way" is to create Single Page Applications (SPAs) and use WebSockets. If you must be old-fashioned, try ngCookies.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies